# XAMPP will not start Apache and MySql servers

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Here is what the [control panel looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJ6Z.png)

[But the output over here seems like it's working??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDF9x.png)

So far I've tried a whole bunch of terminal commands to force it to start and none of them have worked so far. Then I tried reinstalling but the same problem. I tried changing the port but that didn't work either.

When I run php files in the htdocs folder it works fine though, but phpMyAdmin doesn't connect.

This is [error I get when trying to connect to phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po1yy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Having just spent hours on this problem, the following answer helped me:

"If the problem is not a busy port you can also try the following: select "show debug information" in the XAMPP config panel. you will find this option in config panel enable this option and click save it will display the files that are being executed, like when starting Apache you'll be shown something like "Executing "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe". If you run the same command in cmd prompt it will clearly display the error with file name and line number.

All you need to do is to find the respective file dig in the code and resolve it.Your problem will be [may be] solved."